# Algebraic set defined by element in coordinate ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Given an algebraic set $Y=Z(T)$ and consider $\overline{f}\in A(Y)$. Can we safely conclude that
$$Z(\overline{f})=\{P\in\mathbb{A}^n_k| f(P)=0,\forall f\in\overline{f}\}=Z(f)\cap Z(T)$$
I think we can because the set $\overline{f}$ contains all possibilies of $f+g$ where $g\in (T)$. Hence $Z(f+g)=Z(f)\cap Z(g)$. Is there any mistakes in the argument?
This question comes from my attempt in solving the exercise 1.1.8 from Hartshorne. Thank you!

Comment: There's room for improvement here. Where does $Y$ live? Where do all of these intersections live? It's not really correct to say $Z(f+g)=Z(f)\cap Z(g)$, there's some missing explanation here. On the other hand, you're sort of on track to say something true - why don't you give this another pass while trying to be more precise?